# Is there a site (or one being developed) that contains a library of Plutus smart contracts?

Tags: smart-contract, learning

Can someone direct me to a site where I can search for specific Plutus smart contracts? It would be useful both for inspiration, and also to reduce the amount of redundant work spent creating smart contracts across different teams. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure anyone has gone out and created that yet, but here is a link to the [use-cases](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-use-cases/src/Plutus/Contracts) repository put together by IOHK. These contracts are a pretty solid spot to take design ideas from.

Comment: Thanks for the resource. It's not as extensive as I was hoping, but still helpful.